# pattern-matching with ANY()

Tags: sql, postgresql, any

I have a table of 3 columns among which one is a text array of non-uniform lengths (modules). I want to create a derived table depending on the presence of an element in modules array matching a definite text-pattern/phrase. The element name can also vary though it will have a common phrase. 
A non-working example is given below:

```
    select machine_id, jobid, 
    case
    when '%charmm%' LIKE ANY(modules) then 'CHARMM'
    when '%gaussian%' LIKE ANY(modules) then 'GAUSSIAN'
    else 'OTHERS'
    end as package, modules
    from jobapps limit 50;
```

In this case, there could be several module names of Gausiian: gaussian/16b01, gaussian/09e01. But I want to focus on the phrase 'gaussian'  and create a new column where all the entries matching with the text-pattern 'gaussian' will be tagged as 'gaussian'.

This is why I wanted to use '%gaussian%' LIKE ANY(modules)  and this is not working.

I could use: 'gaussian/09e01' LIKE ANY(modules), but in that case I have to write all possible values, and if a user creates a new module of Gaussian, then that data will be missed.

Is there any way to rectify the above problem? Or is there any better way to achieve the goal?

```
    select machine_id, jobid, 
    case
    when '%charmm%' LIKE ANY(modules) then 'CHARMM'
    when '%gaussian%' LIKE ANY(modules) then 'GAUSSIAN'
    else 'OTHERS'
    end as package, modules
    from jobapps limit 50;
```

I want to get something like:

```
    machine_id | jobid  | package  |         modules          
    ------------+--------+----------+--------------------------
    6 | 1884 | CHARMM   | {charmm}
    2 | 2305 | CHARMM   | {charmm}
    6 | 786  | GAUSSIAN | {gaussian/09e1}
    7 | 1956 | CHARMM   | {charmm}
    3 | 72037| NAMD     | {namd,intel/2018}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `LIKE` operator requires that the pattern be on the right, while the `ANY()` expression will always use the array members as the right operand, so I don't think there's an easy way out.

You could create your own "reverse like" operator with the operands reversed:

```
create function reverse_like(text,text) returns boolean as
'select $2 like $1'
language sql immutable;

create operator <~~ (
  function = reverse_like,
  leftarg = text,
  rightarg = text
);
```

...and then query your array with:

```
case
when '%charmm%' <~~ ANY(modules) then 'CHARMM'
when '%gaussian%' <~~ ANY(modules) then 'GAUSSIAN'
```

If you don't want to create a new operator just for this query, I think you'll have to do it the long way, by unnesting the array and checking the contents in a subquery:

```
case
when exists (select 1 from unnest(modules) u(v) where v like '%charmm%') then 'CHARMM'
when exists (select 1 from unnest(modules) u(v) where v like '%gaussian%') then 'GAUSSIAN'
```

... or alternatively:

```
case
when (select bool_or(v like '%charmm%') from unnest(modules) u(v)) then 'CHARMM'
when (select bool_or(v like '%gaussian%') from unnest(modules) u(v)) then 'GAUSSIAN'
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This actually worked for me. I may like to add one more question here:  An array have more than one entries. For example, it may be {gaussian, intel, cuda}, in another case {cuda, intel}.   In the first case, I want to tag this as 'GAUSSIAN', and in the second case where no standard application module is absent, I want to tag this as 'Custom code'.  Now, the ANY() function can only return TRUE if any one of the element is matching with the search-pattern. I would like go through all array elements and check if any standard-app is present, otherwise tag it as 'Custom code'.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this differs from your current query. You should post this as a new question.